# Android how to keep NetworkCallback alive in background

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-wifi

I'm trying to monitor the WiFi state (connect/disconnect) of the phone in background, but whenever I close the application ConnectivityManager will no longer call the provided method. How would I keep the registration alive even in the background?

Some SO questions pointed to [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) source that instructs on how to use Services in android, and has been implemented here. Unfortunately the method does not work, even after trying to test and tweak it multiple times (such as using alternative classes to AsyncTask).

### Service that should keep the process alive in the background

```java
public class MonitorService extends Service implements Runnable {
    private final LocalBinder binder;
    private WifiChecker checker;

    {
        binder = new LocalBinder();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        checker = new CallbackChecker(MonitorService.this, new WallPaperChanger());
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public MonitorService getService() {
            return MonitorService.this;
        }
    }

    public MonitorService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return binder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        checker.destroy();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        AsyncTask.execute(this);
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

### How MainActivity starts the service above

```java
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MonitorService.class);
startService(serviceIntent);
```

### How ConnectivityManager is being used

```java
public class CallbackChecker extends WifiChecker {
    private ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback callback;

    public CallbackChecker(Context context, WifiListener... listeners) {
        super(context, listeners);
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkRequest.Builder builder = new NetworkRequest.Builder();

        cm.registerNetworkCallback(builder.build(), callback = new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAvailable(Network network) {
                WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
                // Some code that runs when wifi is connected
            }

            @Override
            public void onLost(Network network) {
                // Some code that runs when wifi is disconnected
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d("DEBUG", "DESTROYED");
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        cm.unregisterNetworkCallback(callback);
    }
}
```

In the code we can see that a debug message should be sent when the service is destroyed, but this never gets printed to the console. The method should be called when the service is destroyed, and as such it may point out that the service itself never gets destroyed. Unfortunately due to my lack of expertise on Android development (first app) I don't know how I would continue with this problem/question

Answer (score 1):

If you want to monitor it continuously, you could use a Foreground Service with a partial wakelock, in order to prevent the phone from sleeping.
Here below an example of Foreground Service Class that implements a Wakelock:

```
public class ICService extends Service {
    
    private static final int ID = 1;                        // The id of the notification
    
    private NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;                 // PARTIAL_WAKELOCK
    
    /**
     * Returns the instance of the service
     */
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public ICService getServiceInstance(){
            return ICService.this;
        }
    }
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();      // IBinder
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // PARTIAL_WAKELOCK
        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,"INSERT_YOUR_APP_NAME:wakelock");
    }
    
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        startForeground(ID, getNotification());
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
    
    @SuppressLint("WakelockTimeout")
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        if (wakeLock != null && !wakeLock.isHeld()) {
            wakeLock.acquire();
        }
        return mBinder;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // PARTIAL_WAKELOCK
        if (wakeLock != null && wakeLock.isHeld()) {
            wakeLock.release();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private Notification getNotification() {
        final String CHANNEL_ID = "YOUR_SERVICE_CHANNEL";

        builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID);
        //builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_24dp)
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.YOUR_RESOURCE_ICON)
            .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryLight))
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setShowWhen(false)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW)
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setContentText(composeContentText());

        final Intent startIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ICActivity.class);
        startIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        startIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        startIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 1, startIntent, 0);
        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        return builder.build();
    }
}
```

In your manifest you should declare:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Obviously you still have also to disable battery optimization and monitoring for your app, and allow the background network activity.
You can browse a real working example of this service on a GPS Logging app [here](https://github.com/BasicAirData/GPSLogger/blob/master/app/src/main/java/eu/basicairdata/graziano/gpslogger/GPSService.java).

Using a foreground service, a notification icon will be present on your system bar.